# Can you perform linear migrations on a Synced Realm in Realm JS?

Tags: react-native, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-migration

I have had no problems with doing Realm JS linear migrations on a local Realm when following this example in the docs: https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#linear-migrations

However when I have attempted to do Realm JS linear migrations on a local Realm that is synced with the Realm Object Sever, I run into errors.

This leads me to believe that performing linear migrations is not supported. Or there may just be some bugs. Any clarifications regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated. And I'm more than happy to provide error messages and snippets of my code.

The main error that is causing me problems is after a synced Realm has been opened for the first time any attempts following that at retrieving the schemaVersion at the same path result in the following error:

```
Realm.schemaVersion('<path to realm>');

Expected A Realm with no or in-realm history.
```

Comment: The difference is that local Realms have schema mode `AUTOMATIC`, while (last time I checked) sync Realms have schema mode `ADDITIVE`. So AFAIK when you *open* a sync Realm, if the schema contains fields/objects/etc that are not yet in the schema, then they get added automagically. But this was with ROS 1.x so i might be out of date on this

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thanks for the insight. I have seen some error messages pertaining to that Additive schema mode. Will have to keep that in mind moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

For a synchronized Realm you can freely add new types and new properties to existing types, but changing the types of existing properties is not supported, and the migration functionality for local Realms is not used.

Removing properties and types from your schema definition is allowed, but does not actually delete the data for those properties from the REalm.

Comment: Really appreciate your reply. Have some more questions:  
1. What happens if the name of an existing Property is changed? Is this considered to be a new Property and the Object values for it are are empty?  
2. Is it advisable to migrate data in some adhoc way if for example you add new columns? Or new seed data?

Comment: Renaming a property is indistinguishable from removing the property and adding a new unrelated one.